# Auto Populate Gallery From Two Folders

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox, gallery

I have been searching the net for a couple of days now and I still can't seem to find what I want. And I'm such a noob at php that I have no idea how to come up with it myself. I know one of you guys could help me out with this.

I want to auto populate a fancybox gallery. I already created a code that can auto populate a gallery from a folder, but I can't get it to populate two tags within that gallery: "a href" and "img src".

```
<div id="content">
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="thumb/#"><img    src="images/#" alt=""/></a>
</div>

<?php

$dirname = "./images";
$images = scandir($dirname);
$ignore = Array(".", "..");
foreach($images as $curimg){
if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
echo "<img src='./images/$curimg' /><br>\n";
};
}     
?>
```

As you can see, it only populates the  tag from one folder. But I want it to populate two folders for both tags; one different folder for each tag, "a href" and "img src".

Your help will be greatly appreaciated. :)

Comment: It may just be me, but it isn't entirely clear what the desired result is. Could you please elaborate or show what your desired output is?

Comment: I want to populate <a href="#"> and <img src="#"> from two different folders. I want them to echo into one line of script so that when you click on the <img> the <a href=> pictures popup with fancybox.

Comment: Ok, easiest solution is to name images like image1.jpg, and image1_thumb.jpg, then just few modifications in existing script are needed. And yes, you always should have same number of images in both folders, of course. :)

Comment: I never thought about that. I think that should work. Thanks for the idea! :)

Comment: Anyone have an example of how I might go about with nevermind's idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out with some help from another member.

```
<?php
$directory = 'thumb';   //where the gallery thumbnail images are located    
$files = glob($directory."/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE);
natsort($files); //sort by filename
?>

<?php
for($x = 0; $x < count($files); $x++):
$thumb = $files[$x];
$file = basename($thumb);
$nomargin = $x%4 == 0?" nomargin":"";
$title = htmlspecialchars($file);
?>
<div class="thumbs fancybox<?= $nomargin ?>"
 style="background:url('<?= $thumb ?>') no-repeat 50% 50%;">
 <a rel="group" href="images/<?= $file ?>" title="<?= $title ?>"><?= $title ?></a> 
</div>
<?php
endfor;
?>
```